# Prove that $n^n$ is not divisible by $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How can I prove that $n^n$ is not divisible by $n!$ for $n \geq 3$.

Comment: For $n \geqslant 3$, you have $\varphi(n) > 1$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: If this is homework, please say so. It will help you if you show your working too :)

Comment: No this is not homework. Just an expression which I need in some problem solving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In particular, $n$ is not the product of all primes less than $n$. Thus, there is a prime number $p<n$ such that $p$ does not divide $n$. Since $p$ divides $n!$, it follows...

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Consider $n-1$. Prove that this is a divisor of one, but not of the other.

Comment: Seems the hint is not enough for me. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If two numbers don't have the same divisors, then they are not equal.

Comment: If $a$ is divisible by $b$, then in particular $a$ is divisible by _any divisor_ of $b$.